# Accessing sender on MouseButton1Down

Tags: roblox

Is it possible to access the ImageButton that was pressed when the MouseButton1Down event occurs?

I was hoping to do this;

```
local function btnOnPressed(property1)
    local buttonThatWasPressed = ....??? <--- can this be done?
    -- do stuff based on some of the imagebuttons properties such as image source
end

button1.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function() btnOnPressed("stuff")   end)
button2.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function() btnOnPressed("stuff")   end)
```

I know I can pass a property to the function, but that's not what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is just to use the existing reference to your button and pass it to your function as an argument.

```
local function btnOnPressed(buttonThatWasPressed, property1)
    -- do stuff based on some of the imagebuttons properties such as image source
end

button1.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function(mouseX, mouseY)
    btnOnPressed(button1, "stuff")
end)
button2.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function(mouseX, mouseY)
    btnOnPressed(button2, "stuff")
end)
```